# Closing forms after successful submission Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form in my rails 3 app that is used to create new tags. This page is opened in a new window and I would like for that window to close after a successful submission of a new tag. How should I go about doing that.

I tried `<%= f.submit "Create Tag", :onclick => "window.close()" %>` and that didn't work - it still followed through with the redirection.

How might I redirect to a javascript file that would close the window?

---

Here I tried to redirect to another html page, but it still doesn't close when I use rails,  even though it works when I just load it manually.

```
> <!DOCTYPE html> <html>   <head>
>     <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">  
> </head>
> 
>   <body id="sample"
> onload="window.close()">
>     This page was meant to close itself immediately using javascript.
> If it has not, please close it
> manually.   </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the best answer on this forum and it seems to work ... I'm not quite sure why.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=23c03746e3aa03f9&hl=en

```
window.open('', '_self', '');
window.close();
```

Comment: Nice! But how would you render this as a response to a controller action (or would this need to be in a partial)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `render :text => '<script type="text/javascript"> window.close() </script>` in your controller to close the window afterwards.

An alternative solution could be `render :action => "window_closer"` with windows_closer.html.erb being a HTML file with the same code (and maybe a body and a "Please close window now" text).

Comment: Did you look at the source of that page? There should be the `<script ...` stuff. Maybe your browser does not allow you to close windows by javascript. Most browsers allow only allow those windows to be closed that were opened before by the same website using javascript, too. I just wrote a little sample app: open a window with `window.open()` and closing it instantly using `render :text => ...`. Works with Opera Browser and Firefox.

Comment: Hmmm. So I need the opening website to do the closing? I made it so that after a successful submission my site redirects to a page that should close, but it doesn't. I put the source above.

Comment: Not sure why this wasn't the accepted answer. But this is spot on for what the question was when I googled it. +a lot more if I could. Really like this solution